How to forward traffic to another interface in same host
RHEL8. I need to forward only sip/tcp and rtp/udp packets from ens192 to ens0. But for testing I am trying to forward all traffic from ens192 to ens0. ens192 is the main int of VM, IP - 10.10.10.3
ens0 created by command:
nmcli connection add type macvlan ifname ens0 con-name ens0 dev ens192 mode bridge
nmcli connection modify ens0 ipv4.method manual ipv4.addresses 10.10.10.60/24
nmcli connection up ens0

#ip a
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:97:92:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp11s0
    inet 10.10.10.3/24 brd 10.5.76.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.10.40/24 brd 10.5.76.255 scope global secondary ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe97:9295/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: ens0@ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c2:8b:80:c5:80:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.60/24 brd 10.5.76.255 scope global noprefixroute ens0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.10.40/24 brd 10.5.76.255 scope global secondary ens0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::57ab:83c3:8a99:230d/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

10.10.10.40 - is virtual address of cluster between 2 nodes.
forwarding enabled net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
firewalld stopped, will use iptables:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.60
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens192 -o ens0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens0 -o ens192 -j ACCEPT
iptables-save

This configuration isnt working.. tcpdump -i ens0 is empty, only ARP packets... help whats wrong?
ip route
default via 10.10.10.1 dev ens192 proto static metric 100
10.10.10.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.3 metric 100
10.10.10.0/24 dev ens0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.60 metric 410

Also tryed to create tap/tun interfaces with different networks. Tried to use firewalld... not working

You are not making any sense. Adding a (bridge mode) MACVLAN is more or less the same as bridging. Usually the MACVLAN is moved to another network namespace (used by e.g. a container). By default the netns/container won't be able to communicate with where (like, the "host side") the "attached interface" (e.g. ens192 in this case) is, unless another MACVLAN is also added there (and in that case the IP configuration on the "attached interface" should be "moved" onto that MACVLAN). And neither IP forwarding nor port forwarding/DNAT has anything to do with MACVLAN or bridging.

You really need to clarify what you exactly mean by / refer to with "forward". Besides, suppose some traffics arrived at the host through ens192, where/what  exactly do you want it to go? (By that I don't mean like what arbitrary interface / IP address, but like what exactly is the story / context / goal here?) IP forwarding is really about routes, that is, it just pass the traffic on according to the system routing tables and rules, whereas port forwarding or DNAT is often used to change the destination IP so that another route would be used (e.g., "triggering" IP forwarding, you may say).
